# dataset won't change the cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I just ran into another problem that my brain just cant see the solution into. this is what I see people is talking about that fixed their problem but whenever I try it it wont change cuz it tells me it needs to be a byte type.
so can someone spot what I did wrong in my code?

```
    private void BindData()
    {
        // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
        // to the GridView control.
        DataSet ds = db.GetData(queryString);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName = "AdminNavn";
            ds.Tables[0].Columns[3].ColumnName = "KundeNavn";
            ds.Tables[0].Columns[7].ColumnName = "Prioritet";
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4] = "Afventer Svar";
                }
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7] = "Lav";
                }

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString() == "2")
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4] = "Svaret";
                }
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString() == "2")
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7] = "Mellem";
                }

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString() == "3")
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7] = "Høj";
                }
            }
            ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            //Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you debug your code and check first your if condition return true or not ?

Comment: they all returned true yes and did what they wanted but got stuck at "afventer svar" but I fixed it from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just fast indput that I found the solution myself now.

if anyone will run into this then the solution was that I was running with tinyint inside the database so the dataset would not allow my strings.
I change the database into varchar instead so I could have a text file there

Comment: Awesome that you posted the answer to your own question. Please consider marking it as accepted so that other people who need this answer know to look here.

Comment: yeah I will but can only do it after 2 days so far what I see